# htaccess rewrite index.php and redirect if without www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

my site url is www.site.com

if user visits = site.com i need to redirect in 301 to www.site.com

if user visits = www.site.com/index.php/asd i need to redirect in 301 to www.site.com/asd

if user visits = site.com/asd i need to redirect in 301 to www.site.com/asd

are all these conditions possible from .htaccess file? does anyone can help me guys? :)

thanks ;)

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/145109/howto-redirect-http-to-https-on-the-same-httpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: i mean that code is redirecting me from site.com to www.site.com  but if i go to site.com/asd  it redirects me to www.site.com/index.php/asd while i would like to be redirected to www.site.com/asd

Comment: That is quite strange. Are you sure above is the only code in your .htaccess file? No where above it is sending it to `index.php/asd`. In fact 2nd RewriteRule above is making 'index.php/asd` to `/ads`. If you can paste some relevant portion snippet of your access.log that will also help to debug this.

Comment: this is my actual code:    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
Options +FollowSymlinks
rewritecond %{http_host} ^site.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Comment: Oh alright. So it is your this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` that is causing trouble. I don't have that in my answer above. Can you comment this and try.

Comment: Based on your comments I have updated my answer to include all the changes.Please copy/paste this into your .htaccess and let me know.